# Magento : Right Sidebar on Popular Search Term page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Configuration of `<catalogsearch_term_popular>` is set as not to display `left` and `right` sidebar.

```
 <catalogsearch_term_popular translate="label">
        <label>Popular Search Terms</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
```

How to update `local.xml` so that I can bring back the **removed** right reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the xml is parsed means that all the remove statements bubble to the bottom. In some cases you can simply add the block back in with another name, but the same alias.

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="my_right" as="right" translate="label">
    <label>Right Column</label>
</block>
```

Unfortunately this only really works with leaf nodes, i.e. nodes that will never be used as references from other xml layout files. Since right and left are container nodes not leaf nodes this won't work. I've never personally used the code, but I have previously come across [a workaround by Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_layout_unremove_in_local_xml), which is probably worth a look.

The only other option is to create a copy of catalogsearch.xml in your theme, and take out the two removes from that layout handle. This file will overload the original and not remove the nodes, but this is a poor option since any changes to the catalogsearch.xml file in future releases will not been seen when using your theme.

Comment: Yeah, I also ended up using that extension.

Comment: you can fillow this
http://magentocodes.blogspot.in/2014/04/show-popular-search-terms-in-sidebar.html